# Run python script under conda env from terminal - macos

Tags: python, macos, terminal, conda

I have a conda environment called 'my_env" with pandas library in it. But when I did the following:

1. `conda activate my_env`
2. `python my_script.py`

I was getting:

> ```
> import pandas as pd 
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
> ```

What's wrong with it?
.
.
Update (10.11.2023)
I've found how to fix this issue: deactivate conda environment till there will be no `(my_another_environment)` shown in the terminal line and then activate the needed one again.
I have no idea why is that but it works for me.

Comment: Did you install pandas?

Comment: When you make virtual environments you also need to install the modules you need like it was a new installation.

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: it's in the description: "with pandas library in it"

Answer (score -1):

After activating env in first you must install libraries that you need.
Like:

```
pip3 install pandas
```

Comment: Of course I did. Did you read the description at all?